# Angular 6 to 7 upgrade resulting an error of missing startup module using lazy loading concept

Tags: angular, angular6, lazy-loading, angular7

**UPDATE On my question**

I have added `"BaseUrl": "./",` to `tsconfig.app.json` and I got the following error:

> error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'BaseUrl'.

I think they mean in `tsconfig.json` and the baseUrl already added in.

**END of Update**

I updated my angular project to angular 7 [using](https://medium.com/@jeroenouw/upgrade-to-angular-7-beta-within-10-minutes-c14fc380edd) the following commands:

```
npm install @angular/animations@latest @angular/common@latest
    @angular/compiler@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest 
    @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest 
    @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest 
    @angular/platform-server@latest 
    @angular/router@latest --save
```

And:

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest 
@angular/compiler-cli@latest 
@angular/cli@latest 
@angular/language-service@latest --save-dev
```

And:

```
npm install core-js@latest zone.js@latest --save
```

And:

```
npm install @types/jasmine@latest @types/node@latest 
codelyzer@latest karma@latest karma-chrome-launcher@latest 
karma-cli@latest karma-jasmine@latest 
karma-jasmine-html-reporter@latest 
jasmine-core@latest jasmine-spec-reporter@latest 
protractor@latest tslint@latest --save-dev
```

And:

```
npm install typescript@latest --save-dev
npm install rxjs@latest rxjs-compat@latest --save

npm install rxjs-tslint@latest --save-dev
```

The resulting `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.19",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.3",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^1.2.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "jspdf": "^1.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "tether": "^1.4.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.11",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.3",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.5",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "webpack": "^4.25.1"
  }
}
```

On `ng serve --port=8000` I am getting the following error:

> core.js:12584 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find
>   module '../app/dashboard/dashboard.module' Error: Cannot find module
>   '../app/dashboard/dashboard.module'
>       at $_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:5
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:388)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.js:14143)
>       at

It was working when I was using `Angular 6`, and i received it only after upgrading.

I tried the [solution](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10673) mentioned on github:

> Efectively, there are three posible solutions:
>
> a) Using relative path loadChildren: './...
>
> b) Using absolute path starting with loadChildren: 'src/app/...
>
> c) tsconfig.app.json --> BaseUrl: "./"

And neither of them worked for me.

Here is my startup routing file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './forgot-password/forgot-password.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path:'',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'forgot',
    component: ForgotPasswordComponent
    //canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path:'dashboard',
    loadChildren: './app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'

  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Am I missing an upgrade or Angular 7 implies us to change routing urls for a specific new form?

Quoting another solution from the github answer which assume that the problem is from the form of `baseUrl`:

> @filipesilva I saw your commit angular/devkit@33af719 The property has
>   moved from tsconfig.app.json to src/tsconfig.json file, but not it's
>   value ./, therefore newly generated v6 apps by CLI wont be able to
>   find lazy load modules with paths defined as lazy load documentation.
>
> I suggest this change. It preserves baseUrl: "./" on tsconfig.json and
>   each project have its tsconfig.app.json that overwrites baseUrl
>   property. I hope this is aligned with the multiprojects approach and
>   tooling.
>
> If you prefere to use relative url for loadChildren, It should be
>   updated on documentation and tutorial.

Comment: You tried all the possible solutions in the github issue?

Comment: did this work `{path: '', loadChildren: () => AdminModule}`??

Comment: Yes @inthevortex but to be sure, I will repeat the process.

Comment: Check my update on top of my question. And about `AdminModule`, where to add it ?

Comment: @inthevortex loading `AdminModule` directly would defeat the purpose, OP wants to load module lazily. The way suggested would load module eagerly.

Comment: Okay, but where should I add this line `{path: '', loadChildren: () => AdminModule}` ?

Comment: @inthevortex okay you mean as I am naming them, I should replace `loadChildren: "./app/dashboard..."` to `{path: '', loadChildren: () => dashBoardModule}` ???

Comment: Okay, worked. i will post an answer about it. Thanks @inthevortex

Comment: @PankajParkar so it isn't a good idea ? Because it worked for me

Comment: @alim1990 it would work, but all the module will be loading eagrly, eventually that will increase the final bundle size, and initial load time will get increase, that's why lazy load came into picture to solve this problem.

Comment: @PankajParkar so what to do ? I will get back to `loadChildren: "./app/dashboard/..."` but still not working.

Comment: @alim1990 can you please replicate this issue on stackblitz, with minimum code, I'd love to look into it. Thanks :)

Comment: @PankajParkar it would take few minutes but I will start working on it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183352/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-alim1990).

Comment: Anything new guys still having the same problem.